# JsReact how to render using variables

Tags: php, reactjs, dom

Im using react js to render html class names on a page that Im building.
Below is my code,

**Gathering data and storing in variables**

```
whats_the_status = this.props.data.is_user_profile ? 111 : 222;

prem_member += this.props.data.premium_member > 0 ? 'positive' : 
this.props.data.premium_member < 0 ? 'negative' : '';
temp_memeber = this.props.data.given_one_day.value ? "+1" : "";

temp_or_premium = whats_the_status == 111 ? '{ className:' + prem_member + '}' : whats_the_status == 222 ? 'null, ' + 11 + ',' : '';
```

**Rendering using the variables from earlier**

```
_react2.default.createElement(
 'span',

 temp_or_premium,
 )
```

The above variable "temp_or_premium" is what prints class names or values inside the html. But the problem is, its not loading the class name or values. Instead, I get one of  the following rendered in my html

"**undefinied positive**" 

OR
"**undefinied negative**" 
OR 
"**undefinied null 11**"

Thanks in advance !

Comment: where is the initilisatoion of `prem_member `?

Comment: variables are defined in the the actual code, I just didnt want to add it here to simplify the code - thanks :)

Comment: basically  the initial value `prem_member ` coming undefined.snippet shared here working fine as per the output shared

Comment: Hmm, thats a good point, I've defined it as this `var prem_member;` but still not working

Comment: `var prem_member = "some value"`

Comment: That was clever, I also tried something similar but it renders the value infront of the result now. So rather than **undefinied null 11** it prints **some valuenull 11** now

Comment: So,is it expected?Please add some space during initilisation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165190/discussion-between-mark-and-riyaj-khan).

Comment: But the problem is, its not registering as a class name in the html, its just printing the class name as text. Any ideas why this is